# Alignt two elements to opposite sides of a DIV without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a DIV that contains two elements, a `<h2>` and a `<button>`. They should be on opposite sides (left-right) of the container. I have managed to do that using absolute positions on the child elements:

```
#header2{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.4em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #CC3333;
    min-height: 100px;
}

h2{
    position: absolute;
    display:inline;
}


#button{
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: .1em;
    width:100px;
    height: 80%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Now I find that those elements overlap when they don't fit on a smaller screen. I understand this is caused because of the absolute position, which makes those elements ignore the layout flow. So, what I'm trying to find is a way of align the elements on opposite sides and keeping the layout flow of the div, to make it more flexible.

Comment: Why can't you just set a `min-width` on `#header2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to [float](http://www.elated.com/articles/css-floats/) them.  But remember to [clear the floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).